# find & replace text using UpdateCursor in ArcMap

Tags: python, replace, find, arcpy, arcmap

In ArcMap I would like to find and replace a portion of an address in a field. For example, I have fields in my geodatabase table like "None  None, , Queenstown". I would like to replace the "None  None, , " with blank text. I was thinking of doing this using the UpdateCursor.

So far I can get the features that contain the "None  None, , ":

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fcOrganisation, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if "None  None, , " in row[0]:
            print "C = %s" % (row[0])
```

This then gives me a list of the rows that contain "None  None, , ":

```
C = None  None, , Stutterheim
C = None  None, , Bhisho
C = None  None, , Queenstown
C = None  None, , East London
C = None  None, , East London
C = None  None, , Port Elizabeth
C = None  None, , Alice
C = None  None, , Port Elizabeth
```

I now want to replace just the "None  None, , " so that I only get the town names:

```
Stutterheim
Bhisho
Queenstown
East London
East London
Port Elizabeth
Alice
Port Elizabeth
```

I can do this on the field in the table in ArcMap. Is there a way to do this using python/arcpy and using the UpdateCursor?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

make it like this:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fcOrganisation, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        srchStr = "None  None, , "
        if srchStr in row[0]:
            print "C = %s" % (row[0])
            cursor.updateRow(row[0][len(srchStr):])
```